# How to publish GitHub pages into custom sub-path of a domain?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have an organization here: https://github.com/casbin/. I have setup the organization's GitHub pages to this repo: https://github.com/casbin/casbin.github.io and bound the domain: `casbin.org` to it.

Now I want to build a new GitHub pages from this repo: https://github.com/casbin/casbin-gui-editor and publish it to a custom sub-path: `casbin.org/editor`. But when I enable GitHub pages in: https://github.com/casbin/casbin-gui-editor, GitHub directly publishes it to: http://casbin.org/casbin-gui-editor/ instead. See the below screenshot:

[image]

I want it to be published to `casbin.org/editor` instead of `casbin.org/casbin-gui-editor`. But I didn't find a place to modify it. I attempted to modify the below `Custom domain` input box but it doesn't allow me to specify a sub-path like `casbin.org/editor`.

I know I can finally solve this issue by renaming my repo to the sub-path I want, but it makes my repo name obscure. So I'd still like to find other ways. Any other ways to do it?

Comment: Are you at liberty to rename the repository to `casbin/editor`?

Comment: @Chris  I know I can finally solve this issue by renaming my repo to the sub-path I want, but it makes my repo name obscure. So I'd still like to find other ways. Any other ways to do it?

Comment: I'm not clear how `casbin/editor` is somehow more obscure than `https://casbin.org/editor/`, but it's your project.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me, I mean https://github.com/casbin/casbin-gui-editor is less obscure than https://github.com/casbin/editor

Comment: I understand that. But you're asking how to use `https://casbin.org/editor/` on GitHub Pages. Why is `/editor/` better there if it's not clear enough on GitHub, where you want to use `casbin/casbin-gui-editor`? Doesn't the user / org name of `casbin` provide the same kind of context that `https://casbin.org/` provides? Asked another way, doesn't `casbin/casbin-gui-editor` seem slightly redundant, in much the same way that `https://casbin.org/casbin-gui-editor/` is?

Comment: Sounds fair. I already renamed my repo to: https://github.com/casbin/editor/. But I'm still pleasant to hear any technical ways to modify the sub-path.